# why show me error 419 "page expired" in laravel 6 when send a post request?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

when i post a request to "http://localhost:8000/about" with application postman 
i get error

> 419 | page expired

routes/web.php:

```
<?php

Route::post('/about', 'HomeController@about')->name('about');
?>
```

App/Http/Controller/HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\IndexRequest;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function about(IndexRequest $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you added csrf protection.?

Comment: Are you posting with CSRF token in your form?

Comment: how i can add CSRF token with application postman ?

Comment: send `_token=xxx` post data where xxx is csrf token